# How to read parameters estimate in R

Tags: r, parameters, linear-regression

I am working on the file wm1.txt belonging to the package alr3 in R. I have to find the parameters estimate for this function: E(log(Y)|X=x) = beta_0 + beta_1 log(x) + beta_2 log(x)^2 where Y is CSdp and X is RSdp. When I write the coefficients function in R, I obtain this:

> coefficients(lm(CSlog~I(RSpd)+I(log(RSpd))+I(log(RSpd)^2)))

(Intercept)        I(RSpd)   I(log(RSpd)) I(log(RSpd)^2)

```
1.30032161     0.00079405     0.12505971     0.13885632
```

So, given that beta0 is the intercept so the corresponding value is 1,30032161, what are the values for beta1 and beta2?
I think that are beta1=0.1250 and beta2=0.1388 but then what is the other value 0.0007?

Thank you!

PS. as you can see in the formula there is CSlong instead of CSpd becuase I set also CSlog <- log(CSpd) assuming that the function requires E(log(Y)|X=x) .. don't know if it is correct

Comment: The reason for the extra coefficient is because your model formula has an `RSpd` term. To specify the model without it, use: `lm(CSlog~I(log(RSpd))+I(log(RSpd)^2))`

Comment: You are right! It was so simple! Thank you so much :)